# Offline upgrade 12.04 LTS SERVER to 16.04 LTS (live DVD)

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, server, upgrade

I have found a number of threads that address the upgrading using the live DVD but they seem to be all desktop centred.

Can I boot from the 14.04.05 LTS SERVER live CD/DVD to perform an upgrade in the same way as desktop?  After that the same with 16.04.02 LTS server?

The only service on the server in question is SAMBA (3.6.3).

Comment: There have been a LOT of changes between 12.04 and 16.04, including changes to Samba. Don't count on such an upgrade being smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You boot from the cd to *reinstall*.  If you want to upgrade, you use `do-release-upgrade`.  If you happen to have the new server cd you can use `apt-cdrom` to add it as a package source to avoid downloading any packages that are already on the cd.  If you mean that thing the desktop cd does where it deletes the system files, keeps your home directory, and then installs the new release, no, the server cd does not do that as far as I know.

Comment: I managed to get apt-cdrom to add the 14.05 packages but do-release-upgrade just returns with "no new release found".

Comment: added entry to fstab (/dev/sdb1 /media/cdrom auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0). sudo mount /media/cdrom (ok & checked). sudo apt-cdrom -m -d=/media/cdrom. sudo do-release-upgrade.

Comment: @Walter, you mean it works after you manually mounted it?  Odd..  I was going to say that if do-release-upgrade does not know there is a new release, then you must not have run a regular apt-get upgrade on the server in quite some time.  The previous system gets updated to know there is a new one to upgrade to, and normally will just download the packages.  `apt-cdrom` is just so it can find them on the cd instead.

Comment: that's correct an apt-get upgrade has never been done because the servers in question are isolated from the internet and they never will be. If it can't be done from the DVD media then it won't be done.

Comment: @Walter, then you will need to set up your own private archive mirror.   Debian provides multiple DVD images that make up a complete archive for offline installs, but not Ubuntu.  You can mirror the whole archive though, and then either make that available to an internal server, or burn it to dvds if you wish.